# SQL query for returning multiple fields joined to the same reference

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following table, do_stock_movement, that looks like this:

```
stock_movement_id   sm_number   sm_source_id    sm_destination_id
15164b86a7533d           145    1516478840ee29  151644d8bd63f2
15166b89d1a9fc           194    15165c481bd9d0  151659e632cd48
```

The columns `sm_source_id` and `sm_destination_id` both reference product points stored in `do_product_points`.

I'm using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM do_stock_movement
INNER JOIN do_product_points ON product_points_id = sm_source_id
WHERE sm_number = '145'
```

In `do_product_points`, there's a field called `pp_name`. I need the corresponding `pp_name` for both `sm_source_id` and `sm_destination_id`.

However, the query above will only return the `pp_name` for `sm_source_id`, or for `sm_destination_id` if you change the joined field to that.

What SQL query will return the corresponding `pp_name` for both `sm_source_id` and `sm_destination_id`?

I hope this is clear. Please ask questions if it isn't!

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` this table `do_product_points` one more times for the `sm_destination_id`:

```
SELECT 
  s.pp_name AS SourcePoint,
  d.pp_name AS DestinationPoint,
  ...
FROM do_stock_movement AS m
INNER JOIN do_product_points s ON s.product_points_id = m.sm_source_id
INNER JOIN do_product_points d ON d.product_points_id = m.sm_destination_id
WHERE m.sm_number = '145'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need join twice and use alias:

```
SELECT *, Src.pp_name, Dst.pp_name FROM do_stock_movement
  INNER JOIN do_product_points as Src 
      ON Src.product_points_id = sm_source_id
  INNER JOIN do_product_points as Dst 
      ON Dst.product_points_id = sm_destination_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to the product_points table twice, once with source_id and once with destination_id:

```
SELECT * FROM do_stock_movement move
INNER JOIN do_product_points source ON source.product_points_id = move.sm_source_id
INNER JOIN do_product_points dest ON dest.product_points_id = move.sm_destination_id
WHERE sm_number = '145'
```